# Android Development Frameworks

Tags: android, frameworks

How many different frameworks are available for Android and which one will be the simplest to learn and develop in?

Comment: I'm sorry... it's pretty early *gg* i was just thinking of IDEs not of Frameworks.. so i missed the point i gues... i voted to delete my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best Framework is the Android API itsself i guess. Have a look at developer.android.org which is (IMHO) one of the best documented projects ever. So you don't need another "ontop" Framework to work with Android because the API itsself is easy and well organized.